# PHP: remove `http://` from link title

Tags: php, html, string

I have a string that looks like:

`$string = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>';`

How can I remove the `http://` part from the link text, but leave it in the href attribute?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->replaceLast('http://')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L305) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without using a full blown parser, this may do the trick for most situations...

```
$str = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>';

$regex = '/(?<!href=["\'])http:\/\//';

$str = preg_replace($regex, '', $str);

var_dump($str); // string(42) "<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>"
```

It uses a *negative lookbehind* to make sure there is no `href="` or `href='` preceding it.

[See it on IDEone](http://ideone.com/7zJwA).

It also takes into account people who delimit their attribute values with `'`.

Comment: that works, tx. nice site this ideone, you can actually run php code on it :)

Answer (score 9):

```
$string = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>'; 
$var = str_replace('>http://','>',$string);
```

Just tried this in [IDEone.com](http://ideone.com/Rr44N) and it has the desired effect.

Comment: Just worth throwing out there, this won't catch `> http://...`, but if you trim out the spaces beforehand this should do it.

Comment: Nah, a space between the `<a>` tags, like `<a href='...'> Text </a>`

Comment: @Robert Or newline if you indent your text nodes (I often do for readability.)

Answer (score 4):

In this simple case, the `preg_replace` function will probably work. For more stability, try using `DOMDocument`:

```
$string = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($string);

$link = $dom->firstChild;
$link->nodeValue = str_replace('http://', '', $link->nodeValue);
$string = $dom->saveXML($link);
```

Comment: Just an edge case, you may want to use regex to make sure you strip it off from the beginning only, what about a link like `http://example.com/send-to-friend?url=http://somewhere.com` ? Also, +1 for using a parser.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com';
$str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $str);
echo $str; // www.google.com
```

that will work for both http:// and https://

[running live code](http://codepad.org/eUNIeKwV)

Answer (score 2):

Any simple regular expression or string replacement code is probably going to fail in the general case.  The only "correct" way to do it is to actually parse the chunk as an SGML/XML snippet and remove the `http://` from the value.

For any other (reasonably short) string manipulation code, finding a counterexample that breaks it will be pretty easy.

Comment: Well, the incorrect way is still more appropriate. There's not enough edge case potential to warrant using the overkill solution (html parser) here. A regular expression is sufficient. (The no regex for html parsing meme is somewhat dated.)

Comment: One man's "meme" is another man's correctness.  We don't know how critical it is for this to work all the time, or how trustworthy the input might be.  Regex will probably work, but I don't want to give @Alexandra the impression that their problem solved for every possible input.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "http://" always appears twice on $string, search the string for "http://" backwards using strripos. If the search succeeds, you'll know the start_index of the "http://" you want to remove (and you know the length of course). Now you can use substr to extract everything that goes before and after the chunk you want remove.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>';
$var = explode('http://',$string);
echo $var[2];
```